# How to select the first occurrence in each element by XPath?

Tags: xpath, parent-child

In the following html tags:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h3>
      <a href='http://Ali.org'></a>
    </h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        <a href='http://Mohammad.org'></a>
      </p>
    </div>  
 </div>    
 <div>
  <h4>
    <a href='http://Ali.org'></a>
  </h4>
  <p>
    <a href='http://Mohammad.org'></a>
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to select two '**a**' tags '**http://Ali.org**' & '**http://YaALi.org**'. By the following, I can:

```
//div//a[not(parent::*[not(following-sibling::*)])]
```

But what about a simpler XPath?
By the following, all of '**a**' tags will be selected since they are all the first child of their parents:

```
//div/div//a[1]
```

Or by the following, just the first '**a**' tag will be selected:

```
(//div//a)[1]
```

I want to select 'a' tags that are the first in the 'a' tags of div elements...

Answer (score 2):

`//` in the middle of a path is an [abbreviation for `descendant-or-self::node()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#abbrev), so if you do

```
//div/div//a[1]
```

this effectively means

```
//div/div/descendant-or-self::node()/a[1]
```

This picks the first child `a` of all descendant nodes.  What you want is:

```
//div/div/descendant::a[1]
```

which will pick the first descendant `a`.

Comment: But for the following, this xpath will not select just the first occurrences:                                                                                   <div>
  <div>
    <h3>
      <a href='http://Ali.org'></a>
    </h3>
    <div>
      <p>
       <a href='http://Mohammad.org'></a>
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>    
  <div>
    <h4>
      <a href='http://YaAli.org'></a>
    </h4>
    <p>
      <a href='http://YaMohammad.org'></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: The leading `//` starts a query at all the nodes in the document. `Ali.org` is found when it starts at the outermost `div`, `Mohammad.org` is found when it starts at the first `div` within the outermost `div`. Either you need to give a more specific entry point for your XPath instead of `//`, or maybe just use the XPath you first suggested, if that does what you want.

Comment: Is there a query with CSS selector like this? 
`//div/div/descendant::a[1]`.
CSS selector `first-child` is not the same.

Comment: @meotimdihia I don't think there is a pure CSS selector. With JavaScript, the matching node could be retrieved as follows: `[...document.querySelectorAll('div > div')].map(div => div.querySelector('a')).filter(a => a)`.